# How to add emmet support for .mdx / markdown react file types in vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, markdown, gatsby, emmet

I am using .mdx files in gatsby and want to be able to have emmet recognize this as a valid file type for expansion / support. The `.mdx` files already get recognized in vscode as "Markdown React", and I have previously added .jsx support via:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
```

but can't seem to get it to work for markdown react. I've tried `"javascript": "markdownreact"`, with variations on `"markdown react"`, `"Markdown React"`:

i.e.

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact",
  "javascript": "markdownreact",
},
```

wondering if I either have the language name down wrong still, or if it doesn't support multiple file associations. Or maybe the order should be switched in the key value pair?

Comment: Are you just trying to be able to do the html tags?

Comment: @soulshined yes - just html tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be the canonical answer (or the best one); a solution nonetheless.

Re html tags: One approach is just to enable `html` quickSuggestions in strings:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "html"
},
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    }
},
```

[image: js]

For `.mdx` files specifically, you need to make sure the [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file) is set to Markdown React, or use an extension that incorporates this file association.

Then add it to the included emmet languages:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "mdx": "html"
},
```

[image]

Comment: Almost worked for me. This did: `"emmet.includeLanguages": { "mdx": "html" }`! Thanks!